# Jumbotron borders or outline not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, border, outline

I'll be as descriptive as possible. This is on the latest version of bootstrap.  I have a site that has a large dark image in the background, on certain pages with text on it I put a jumbotron in black for the backdrop of the white lettering. I'd like to put a border around them however thus far I have seen no border in any way I could think of to do this. please help, this is my first website. the border is to give the jumbo tron some light contrast. any questions let me know. using jumbotron my CSS css is

```
.jumbotron {
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-position: 0% 25%;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: white;
text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
background: black;
border: 5px;
border-color: #fff;
}
```

when I use it in the following form on a .php document

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h2> subpage name </h2>
<h4> title </h4>
<p> bunch of text
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Any answers? I am not able to add border

Answer (score 13):

You should insert border-style:solid; in the css style.